# QGIS Change file browser/chooser default location

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

Is there a way to change QGIS file browser default location? Currently it points to bin folder of QGIS installation C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Brighton\bin.

Comment: QGIS should remember the last location used. Does it always show the path to bin even after you have used a different one?

Comment: It depends on file chooser, there are couple in QGIS. In for example distance matrix tool the chooser always points to bin

Comment: That's a plugin. It's behavior is defined by the plugin code and not the core QGIS applicaiton.

Comment: So are you saying that there is no way to set default path like some kind of environment variable?

Comment: Yes, that's the case afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any file selection dialog should remember the last location which was accessed. As far as I know, this works well for all dialogs in the QGIS core but it might not be the case for all plugins.

If you encounter a tool, with a file selection dialog which always defaults to a certain path, e.g. to bin, it would make sense to open a bug report on the (plugin) bug tracker to ask the developer to fix the behavior.